# How change the header size of a frankfurt slide?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How can I increase the header size of a `Frankfurt` slide?

I want two lines of dots. With that height they are cut in half.

Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{Frankfurt}


\makeatletter
  \beamer@compressfalse

\makeatother

\usefonttheme{serif}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!100!bg, fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}


\title{Previsão da Taxa de Câmbio através de modelos baseados na Regra de Taylor}
\date{14 de Fevereiro de 2014}

\begin{document}
(...)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some minimal complete document showing your settings? In particular, what settings are you using for the miniframes (the dots) to appear in two rows?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436), Henrique! As Gonzalo said, it would be great if you could provide us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we can look for a solution. `:)`

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know if you need more code. I'm using the Frankfurt theme. So the dots appear by default when you create a subsection

Comment: Hmmm... Do you get the dots as in the image (in two rows) using the code you just posted?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any additional code before \begin{document} of course

Comment: @Gonzalo: `\beamer@compressfalse` seems to be the culprit; try moving it before the theme selection.

Comment: That specific part of code put the dots in two lines

Comment: @PauloCereda and Henrique Umbelino: with `beamer@compressfalse`, I get a vertical line of dots; commenting it out I get one horizontal line of dots; I don't get the two rows shown in the question.

Comment: @Gonzalo: me too, I can confirm this behaviour.

Comment: @PauloCereda and Henrique Umbelino: I know what was happening; I did some tests with one frame per subsection and many subsections, whereas Humberto is using only two subsections (therefore two rows of miniframes) and many frames per subsection. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redefine the `headline` template and the shading used (in my example code I signaled with `% NEW` the lines in which I changed some lengths, in case you need to make some adjustments):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usefonttheme{serif}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!100!bg, fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}

\makeatletter
\beamer@compressfalse

\AtBeginDocument{
    \usebeamerfont*{headline}
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
         color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
         color(1ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
         color(9ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)% HERE
  }
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-9ex% HERE
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \vskip2ex% HERE
}%
\makeatother

\author{My name}
\title{My presentation}
\institute{My institute}

\newcommand\Text{\frame{\frametitle{test}test}}
\newcommand\Textv{\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\begin{block}{title}
test block
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\Textv\Textv
\subsection{Test subsection}
\Textv

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\Textv
\subsection{Test subsection}
\Textv

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that this solution assumes that there will only be two rows of miniframes (dots); i.e., that you will have less than three subsections per section.

Comment: Your answer solved a problem and create another one!! First, the type of letter changed. Second, all the itemize items disappear =x What happened?

Comment: Gonzalo that code changed my blocks shadows too =x...It can be solved? Thanks

Comment: @HenriqueUmbelino No; my code didn't change any of the things you mentioned. I simply didn't used all of the settings you had since they were not essential to the problem discussed in the question. Simply add the settings for fonts, blocks, etc,, that you originally had in your post.

Comment: @HenriqueUmbelino My bad. You were right about the items issue. Sorry about that; I've fixed the problem in my updated answer.